# sandbox : how to get paypal payment details if failed to return back? -PHP

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-sandbox, payment-processing

I am using Paypal Sandbox for at my site to process payments.

I am saving payment stuffs after the user returned successfully to the store using an URL defined for payment successful/canceled.

But suppose the user loses connection due to any technical issue (e.g. server down or failed internet connection), then how I will get the payment details, especially in cases of the paid orders?

Answer (score 1):

Hi please check this below URL

https://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-aspnet-45-web-forms/checkout-and-payment-with-paypal

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I am looking for the PHP code. Sorry not mentioned properly.